# How to change the unit of y-axis on a histogram in r?

Tags: r

I have data of individual body mass (x axis) plotting against frequency (y axis). I have to divide the existing frequencies (y axis) that i have on the histogram by 60, and then times 1.25, and then log it to get everything to the correct unit. What codes can I use to tell R to do that?

Thanks very much in advance.

Cheers, 
K

Comment: can you give a little more context? `log(frequency/60*1.25)` is surprising (and why not just `log(frequency/48)` ? ) Are you sure you didn't want to transform the body mass rather than the frequency? if so then `hist(log(mass/48))` should be all you need ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to convert the unit back in per surber m^2 from the overall count in all surber samples. For now, im getting values from 0 - 659, and the wanted values are from 2-16 on the y axis. Do you know if I can transfrom the y axis when using the hist function? or I should use plot? @BenBolker

Comment: Still are not explaining why you are using log() in the transformation. That makes things that started out linear become ratios.